# How do I establish a connection between public frontend and private backend both hosted on IIS server

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, iis-8

I am new to this sorry but when hosting public ip frontend and a backend on private ip(on virtual machine),  there is not a connection, no request headers are being sent. Please help how can I configure the iis server to make private backend accessible.
Frontend: Reactjs
Backend: django, django rest framework

Comment: What does private backend mean? Can private backend be deployed in IIS not be accessed?

Comment: Yes sorry for that, by private backend I mean backend is hosted in a private ip address on a virtual machine

Comment: The public frontend is deployed in IIS, and the backend is deployed in a virtual machine hosted by a private IP address. Now you want to connect the frontend to the back end, right?

Comment: Yes correct, I tried doing this by simply sending fetch request from react. But it wouldn't work. The same backend when I host on Heroku on a public ip everything works perfectly.

Comment: Is the network between the IIS server and the virtual machine interoperable?

Comment: Yes it is. The IIS server is on the virtual machine. Both frontend and backend are deployed on different ports of iis server (8000) and (8080) respectively on the virtual machine. But only the frontend(8000) has been given a public ip.

Comment: If the front-end and back-end are on the same server, they should be able to establish a connection.

Comment: Can the backend access the frontend through localhost:8000?